# LINQ query does not compile when using double, float, or decimal instead of int

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following simplified example, which is modeled after code that searches through a list of objects and sorts them by assigning a score to each in an attempt to calculate relevancy (the details of the scoring in the real code aren't relevant here):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserDescription { get; set; }
}

public static void QueryTest()
{
    var somequerytext = "test";
    var accounts = new List<MyClass>();
    var resultsViaInt = accounts.Where( ( MyClass acct, int score ) => 
            MatchInt( acct.UserName, somequerytext, ref score, 2 ) ||
            MatchInt( acct.UserDescription, somequerytext, ref score, 1 ) 
        )
        .Select( ( acct, score ) => new { result = acct, score = score } )
        .OrderBy( x => x.score )
        .Select( x => x.result )
        .ToList();

    var resultsViaDouble = accounts.Where( ( MyClass acct, double score ) => 
            MatchDouble( acct.UserName, somequerytext, ref score, 2.0 ) ||
            MatchDouble( acct.UserDescription, somequerytext, ref score, 1.0 )
        )
        .Select( ( MyClass acct, double score ) => new { result = acct, score = score } )
        .OrderBy( x => x.score )
        .Select( x => x.result )
        .ToList();
}


public static bool MatchInt( string haystack, string needle, ref int score, int weight )
{
    if ( haystack.Contains( needle ) )
    {
        score = score + weight;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool MatchDouble( string haystack, string needle, ref double score, double weight )
{
    if ( haystack.Contains( needle ) )
    {
        score = score + weight;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For some reason, the compiler throws [the following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGgtK.png) for the second query in QueryTest():

For the "accounts" variable:

`'List<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where<MyClass>(IQueryable<MyClass>, Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<MyClass>'`

For the lambda expression inside the query itself:

`Delegate 'Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>' does not take 2 arguments`

I get identical errors if I try to use `double`, `float`, or `decimal`. Using `int`, however, works. I can make the rest of my work with using slightly larger integers instead of doubles, but I would like to get some idea of why the code above won't compile.

The second error seems odd, since the equivalent part of the first query is detected (correctly) as `<Func<MyClass, int, bool>>` whereas the query with the error is missing any reference at all to a parameter in the middle.

Why would it only work for `int`?

Comment: *"the compiler throws the following errors"* -- none of those errors should crash the compiler. Are you sure that's what's happening?

Comment: The second value in the where is an index number like i in : for(i = 0; i < 100) and can't be a double.

Comment: jdweng is right. The question is, what did you intend `score` to be? is it just meant to be a local variable in the lambda?

Comment: @EdPlunkett the intent was to calculate the relevancy for each item in the list and order the results of the query by that. I can think of other code structures to achieve this, but they're all more complex than doing it in the query itself.

Comment: OK, but what value did you think was being passed in in that parameter named `score`? What did you think was the meaning of that number you were getting from `Where()`?

Comment: @jdweng Interesting, I had no idea there was something predetermined like that. Is that because it's in a LINQ query, or is that something that applies to all lambda expressions? I'm pretty sure I've seen multiple parameters used in other lambdas before...

Comment: @Nate That's how `Where()` works. `Where()` is a method. Different methods have different parameters. This stuff is documented. "Oh, I saw somebody call String.Format() with five parameters, why can't I pass five parameters to `Int.Parse()`?"

Comment: [Where with 1 func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)  vs  [The other Where overloadyou are using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @EdPlunkett The intent was that the score would start at 0 and be added to whenever a given item in the list matched something in the query (the addition would be an arbitrary weight). The idea is that once all items that satisfied the query (at all) were determined, they could then be sorted based on those that were most relevant. 

In other words, if the same term were found in multiple fields, that result should come before results where the same term was only found in one field. Like I said, I can think of other ways to accomplish it, but this seemed like the simplest (at the time).

Comment: I think you don't understand what the `Where` you are using actually does. Modifying the `score` parameter does nothing.

Comment: @Nate So the score of the second item in the enumeration is dependent on the score of the first? That explains why the ref parameters. I think what you want isn't really LINQ. Aggregate() is in the ballpark, or a nearby ballpark, but returns a single value. You could declare `score` outside the query -- but that's Contrary to the Spirit of LINQ. Bah humbug, you say -- it works! And I won't argue too hard, I'll just feel a little queasy. But somebody will argue.

Comment: But maybe I misinterpreted "the score would start at 0 and be added to whenever", because you just accepted an answer that calculates score independently for each Acct. It's a good answer, too -- it's exactly what I was within seconds of submitting, but then held off when I saw your last comment.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Not quite. kanders84152's answer below is what I was going for. In addition to misinterpreting the functionality of Where(), I think I had the wrong scope in mind for the score parameter - thinking there was one was tied to each item in the list rather than being just one at the level of the entire query. As for your example above ("why can't i pass x parameters to y") - no need to be rude about it.

Comment: @Nate kanders84152 does have one per item in the list. Not sure I'm understanding you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is pretty close to what you were looking for.

```
        var resultsViaDouble = accounts
            .Select(acct =>
            {
                double score = 0;
                return new
                {
                    match = MatchDouble(acct.UserName, somequerytext, ref score, 2.0) || MatchDouble(acct.UserDescription, somequerytext, ref score, 1.0),
                    score = score,
                    acct = acct
                };
            })
            .Where(x => x.match)
            .OrderBy(x => x.score)
            .Select(x => x.acct)
            .ToList();
```

As to what was wrong with the approach in the OP, I think the comments have explained it thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 2):

the overload of `Where` method which works is :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)
```

(`List<MyClass>` is an IEnumerable)

and `int` parameter stands for index of element in a sequense

there is no such overload with `double` parameter

so you are using `int score` incorrectly here

---

I suggest to transform you code like this:

```
public static double MatchDouble(string haystack, string needle, double weight )
{
    return haystack.Contains( needle ) ? weight : 0;
}
```

```
var resultsViaInt = accounts
    .OrderBy( 
              acct => MatchDouble( acct.UserName, somequerytext, 2.0 ) +
                      MatchDouble( acct.UserDescription, somequerytext, 1.0 )  
            )
    .ToList();
```